# Send moment.js object to server but get Bad request(400) error

Tags: momentjs

When I try to send a request like this:

```
axios.post('/apiUrl', {
    startTime: moment('2021-9-1')
  })
```

I get the Bad Request error:

```
{"startTime":["The value '\"2021-08-31T16:00:00.000Z\"' is not valid."]}
```

I found something strange from the response error:

There are 2 unexpected quotations around the value of time, and was send to server together. it seems that the quotations caused the 400 error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`moment('2021-9-1')` returns a `Moment` object which the format your server does not expect probably. If your server expects a string, then you should format that `Moment` object first.

```
moment('2021-9-1').format()
```

You can pass your format inside `format()`. See [Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

However, you should pass your format when constructing in order to avoid wrong parsing.

```
moment('2021-9-1', 'YYYY-M-D').format()
```